# How to properly use TabNavigator inside another React Component

Tags: ios, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

**Question** - How to properly use **React Navigation**'s TabNavigator container component inside another React component that acts just as wrapper component?

**What I want to achieve** - Basically I want the appbar and tabbar both to be displayed - appbar on the top, tabbar (TabBarTop) just beneath it, a very common design pattern.

I have tried a couple of ways.

**Method #1** (Nesting inside StackNavigator)

*Tab.js*

```
export const Tab = TabNavigator({
    Tab1: { screen: Tab1Container },
    Tab2: { screen: Tab2Container }
  }, {
    tabBarComponent: TapBarTop,
    tabBarPosition: 'top'
  });
```

*AppBar.js*

```
class AppBarComponent extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = { header: null }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        *some more views, buttons blah blah here
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default AppBarComponent;
```

and I use them inside StackNavigator, like

```
export default StackNavigator({
  stack1: { screen: AppBarComponent },
  stack2: { screen: Tab }
});
```

This results in only 1 stack to be displayed at a given time which is exactly how it works. And I don't have anything to do with `initialRouteName`.

**Method #2** (wrapping inside another component)

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <AppBarComponent />
  <Tab />
</View>
```

This on the contrary displays both components but *this.props.navigation.navigate('somepath')*  or  *push()*  or  *pop()* or 
 *replace()*  doesn't work from inside  and . But this.props.navigation and its methods all are available inside those components.

PS - I'm using React Navigation v1 and running on iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@bennygenel your answer is definitely useful in addressing the problem. I kind of fed wrong information when I talk about having components inside TabNavigator. Well, instead of dumb components, there were multiple redux containers inside the TabNavigator as screens and the entire TabNavigator wrapped in a Dumb component. I have edited my question sincerely.

Though `this.props.navigation` exists both inside the redux containers and the wrapper component, the navigation stack reference was different for them which is why methods such as `navigate` or `goBack()` were not working.

The solution was simple. Passing the navigation stack reference as `screenProps` to the wrapper component solves this issue.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <AppBarComponent />
  <Tab screenProps={{ rootNav: this.props.navigation }} />
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution for Method 1

Have a `StackNavigator` with only one screen and show your `TabNavigator` in that screen. Then customize [`header`](https://v1.reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#header) with your custom `AppBarComponent`.

> **header**
>
> React Element or a function that given `HeaderProps` returns a React
>   Element, to display as a header. Setting to `null` hides header.

**Sample**

```
export default StackNavigator({
  stack: { 
    screen: Tab,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: (HeaderProps) => (<AppBarComponent headerProps={HeaderProps} />)
    }
  }
});
```

### Solution for Method 2

You can wrap your component which is not a part of the stack with [`withNavigation`](https://v1.reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop.html) HOC.

> `withNavigation` is a higher order component which passes the
>   navigation prop into a wrapped Component. It's useful when you cannot
>   pass the navigation prop into the component directly, or don't want to
>   pass it in case of a deeply nested child.

**Sample**

```
class AppBarComponent extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = { header: null }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        *some more views, buttons blah blah here
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default withNavigation(AppBarComponent);
```